# Reorder Pipe separated fields with join between 2 fields

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

Input:

```
|Ordernum=8921|mn=03|yr=20|id=869|Name=1|Street=2|City=3|State=4|Zip=5|Country=6|
```

Output:

```
8921,03/20,869,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F\| '{print gensub(/Ordernum=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$2)","gensub(/mn=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$3)"/"gensub(/yr=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$4)","gensub(/id=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$5)","gensub(/Name=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$6)","gensub(/Street=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$7)","gensub(/City=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$8)","gensub(/State=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$9)","gensub(/Zip=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$10)","gensub(/Country=(.*)/,"\\1","g",$11)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/|[^=]*=/,/g; s/|$//; s/,//; s|,|/|2'
```

Or if `mn` and `yr` are not always the second and third fields (but are found in that order):

```
sed 's@|mn\(=[^|]*\)|yr=@|mnyr\1/@; s/|[^=]*=/,/g; s/|$//; s/,//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`, looking for fields with only numbers:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+' -v OFS=',' '{$2=$2 "/" $3; printf "%s,%s,",$1,$2; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){ printf "%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS}}'  <<< "|Ordernum=8921|mn=03|yr=20|id=869|Name=1|Street=2|City=3|State=4|Zip=5|Country=6|"
```

`FPAT` describes how the pattern looks like. In this case, it's composed of number only.

`OFS` is the output field separator that allows formatting with `,`.

The 2nd field is rebuilt with the 3rd. All other are printed as is.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{
         for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)    # iterating through all fields
             if ($i != "") {          # check if field value is not empty
                 c++; sub(/[^=]+=/, "", $i);
                 printf "%s%s", (c > 1? (c == 3? "/" : ",") : ""), $i
             }
             print "" 
     }' FS='|' file
```

The output:

```
8921,03/20,869,1,2,3,4,5,6
```